# Get URL, Title and Description only if Title or Description contains %string%

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a textfile containing the URLs of some RSS feeds. I would like to find out which of these URLs has a title or description (or any other tag) containg certain strings (a list of words).

As for now, I am able to get the URL, title and headline (and whatever). Not really sure on how to proceed though. I guess I would check the tags with regex. If I checked an URLs title and found a wordmatch, how would I then retrieve the URL again? The URL needs to be connected to the tags, like in a .csv. Bit confused here. Maybe someone can shoot me in the right direction?

My path so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rssfeed = open('input.txt')
rss_source = rssfeed.read()
rss_sources = rss_source.split()

i=0
while i<len(rss_sources):
    get_rss = requests.get(rss_sources[i])
    rss_soup = BeautifulSoup(get_rss.text, 'html.parser')
    rss_urls = rss_soup.find_all('link')
    i=i+1

for url in rss_urls:
        rss_all_urls = url.text
        open_urls = requests.get(rss_all_urls)
        target_urls_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_urls.text, 'html.parser')
        urls_titles = target_urls_soup.title
        urls_headlines = target_urls_soup.h1
        print (rss_all_urls, urls_titles, urls_headlines)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do after a word match?

Comment: Basically I want my own feed. So I only want to get those URLs that have a keyword of interest in the title or description. For example: I take the RSS Feed from the NYTimes and only want those documents (URLs) that talk about "social media","facebook","twitter", etc...

Comment: Ok, so why do would you need to retrieve the URL again after a match? It might be helpful to comment this code line by line to describe what's going on

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have an array of URLs. 
That array should contain certain URLs based on some conditions:
- if the Title of that URL match one of the strings contained on an array

So first you need your arrays:

```
titlesToMatch = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
finalArrayWithURLs = []
```

then when you have your: rss_all_urls, urls_titles, urls_headlines for a URL you want to include on the finalArrayWithURLs just those ones that match one of the titles on the titleToMatch

```
for url in rss_urls:
    rss_all_urls = url.text
    open_urls = requests.get(rss_all_urls)
    target_urls_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_urls.text, 'html.parser')
    urls_titles = target_urls_soup.title
    urls_headlines = target_urls_soup.h1

    if any(item in urls_titles for item in titlesToMatch):
        finalArrayWithURLs.push(url)
```

So after that you will have on the finalArrayWithURLs just those URLs where the title match one of the titles of your titlesToMatch array